# MS Access 2010 query match and output

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I was wondering how to go about doing something in Access. 
So I have a two tables, one has data about universities by zip code and the other has a list of counties by zip code.

i.e. 
Table 1

```
Zip code   University
90005       Harvard
90006         yale
90007        columbia
```

Table 2

```
Zip code   county
90005         cook
90006         apple
90007         pineapple
```

My question is whether there is a way to match the zip codes, and create a table that gives me the University and county?

Thanks!

Comment: Unclear, Table2 is zip code and county???

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, i'm looking for a table that has university and county.

Comment: Yes it is called a join. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to JOIN the two tables and then insert the result into the new table

```
SELECT 
    table1.University, 
    table2.county
INTO 
    table3
FROM
    table1 INNER JOIN table2
    ON
    table1.Postcode = table2.Postcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query.

```
select a.zipcode,a.name,b.name
from county a,university b
where a.zipcode=b.zipcode
```

for example see on SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe1fe/1)

Comment: `Access cant use the JOIN Keyword` Is that so? ;)

Comment: You are `SELECTING` the data, but how come is this going to answer the OP's request `a way to match the zip codes, and create a table that gives me the University and county?`